# Split_String en SQL y usar sus valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una operación muy sencilla, pero no sé cómo  proceder.
En un *Stored Procedure* obtengo una cadena llena de Id's separados por comas, entonces necesito separar esa cadena y utilizar su contenido dentro de un `INSERT`. Pero no sé cómo utilizar cada parte de dicho `split` esto es lo que tengo:

```
select * from string_split(@listaDePagosErrores, ',')
  --ahora quiero usar los splits en un insert

INSERT INTO[dbo].[ProgramacionIngresos]
  (IdError)
VALUES
  (split[1]) -- ? ? ? ? o algo así ?
  SELECT * FROM [ProgramacionIngresos]
```

Comment: Tengo un par de observaciones. 1.-¿Qué versión de SQL estás usando? 2.-Para poder ver lo que está pasando vas a tener que poner el código de la función `string_split`. De esta manera vamos a poder saber qué resultados te está trayendo y ver la manera en que hagas tu `insert` a través del `split`.

Comment: v17.17 , pues por lo que entinendo string_split es parte de sql o no?

Comment: hize algunos cambios y me tria lo siguioetne 'El nombre de objeto 'string_split' no es válido.' Una vez investigado eso me entré de que puedo soucionarlo con 'ALTER DATABASE [Mibase] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130' pero cuando ejecuto eso me dice que  = 'nivel de compatibilidad de la base de datos son 90, 100 o 110.' y me quedo igual :s

Comment: Corrijo mi comentario de la versión. `string_split` fue introducido a partir de la versión 13 (SQL Server 2016). Lo que tú me muestras como versión 17.17 es el manejador de la base de datos. Corre el siguiente *script* y dime qué te sale `SELECT @@VERSION`. Con eso sacamos la versión de la base de datos y sabremos si tu versión es la indicada para usar la función de split

Comment: @phi esto:  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)   Feb 10 2012 19:39:15   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo mencionaba en los comentarios. No podrás hacer uso de la función `STRING_SPLIT` ya que fue introducida a partir de la versión 13 (SQL Server 2016) y tú tienes la versión 11.

Vas a tener que construir tu propia función. En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10581814/3200493) de Stack Overflow hay una función que te puede ayudar justo para lo que deseas:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
      @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
      @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Delimiter) -- Diagnostic
--INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString) -- Diagnostic

      DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
GO
```

Para hacer uso de la función sería:

```
SELECT * FROM Split(@ListaPagosErrores)
```

---

Hasta este punto solo tienes una tabla y cada registro separado por el valor declarado en la función. Para hacer el `INSERT` a partir de un `SELECT` sería de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO[dbo].[ProgramacionIngresos]
    (IdError)
VALUES
    SELECT Item AS IdError FROM Split(@ListaPagosErrores)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de poder hacer split a una cadena; yo te sugiero que dentro de un CURSOR uses una función para hacer el split y almacenar los valores en un TABLE, luego haces un WHILE al cursor y dentro de ella haces unos INSERT'S hasta que se termine el bucle.

Te dejo unos ejemplos:

Acá el FUNCTION :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ufn_SplitStrings] ( 
    @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS
@returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS

BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

Acá el CURSOR:

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
    --Acá llamas a la Función que hace el split
    SELECT Name
    FROM [ufn_SplitStrings](@p_cadenaParaSplit)
    WHERE Name <> '';
```

Acá abres y cierras el CURSOR para hacer el WHILE :

```
DECLARE @codigoErrorINT

    OPEN myCursor 
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @codigoError;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acá realizas tu insert's 
            INSERT INTO[dbo].[ProgramacionIngresos](IdError)
                 VALUES (@codigoError)

            FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @codigoError
        END

    CLOSE myCursor 
    DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Pruebas y me cuentas como te fue.

Answer (score 1):

La función string_split está disponible a partir de la versión 2016 de SQL Server. Dicho lo anterior, su implementación vendría siendo de la siguiente manera:

```
declare @ListaPagosErrores varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101'

declare @ProgramacionIngresos table(IDError int)


insert into @ProgramacionIngresos
select [Value]
from string_split(@ListaPagosErrores, ',')



select *
from @ProgramacionIngresos
```